# How to print out values of LSTM gates in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm using a TensorFlow LSTM for a language model (I have a sequence of words and want to predict the next word), and as I'm running the language model, I want to print out the values of the forget, input, transform, and and output gates at each step. How do I do this?

From inspecting the code in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py, I see that the `LayerNormBasicLSTMCell` class has a `call` method that contains the `i, j, f, o` variables that I want to print out.

```
  def call(self, inputs, state):
    """LSTM cell with layer normalization and recurrent dropout."""
    c, h = state
    args = array_ops.concat([inputs, h], 1)
    concat = self._linear(args)

    i, j, f, o = array_ops.split(value=concat, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=1)
    if self._layer_norm:
      i = self._norm(i, "input")
      j = self._norm(j, "transform")
      f = self._norm(f, "forget")
      o = self._norm(o, "output")

    g = self._activation(j)
    if (not isinstance(self._keep_prob, float)) or self._keep_prob < 1:
      g = nn_ops.dropout(g, self._keep_prob, seed=self._seed)

    new_c = (c * math_ops.sigmoid(f + self._forget_bias)
             + math_ops.sigmoid(i) * g)
    if self._layer_norm:
      new_c = self._norm(new_c, "state")
    new_h = self._activation(new_c) * math_ops.sigmoid(o)

    new_state = core_rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(new_c, new_h)
    return new_h, new_state
```

However, is there an easy way for me to print these variables out? Or do I have to basically recreate the relevant lines of code in this method, in my script where I'm running the LTSM?

Answer (score 0):

I used to ask a similar question in git issue. And the response is that original cells only return `c` and `h`(which is also the output `y` of every step). If you want to get the internal variables, you need to do this by yourself.

Here is the link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5731

Comment: Were you able to accomplish this? I am also in need of recording all the LSTM cell gates. However I change the output of the call it breaks too much stuff. Do you have an example of what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do this way:

Firstly return the states you need, for instance, `return new_h, new_state, i, j, f, o`. To make such a change you should copy the source code file from TensorFlow and import it like your own code to your code.
Then in your code, in the `session.run(to_return, feed_dict)`, make the `to_return` like this:

```
output, state, i, j, f, o = lstm_cell(input, state)   
to_return = {
    "new_h": output, 
    "new_state": state,
    "i": i,
    "j": j,
    "f": f, 
    "o": o,
}

results = session.run(to_return, feed_dict) # get what you want from the 
# graph(which are tensors), resulting in results of a dictionary with values
# being numpy arrays. 

print results["i"] # you'll get a numpy array representing the i gate
```

Comment: Here is the error I got after trying your solution: File "rnn.py", line 1327, in static_rnn state_size=cell.state_size) File "rnn.py", line 263, in _rnn_step _maybe_copy_some_through) File "deprecation.py", line 454, in new_func return func(*args, **kwargs) File "control_flow_ops.py", line 2057, in cond orig_res_f, res_f = context_f.BuildCondBranch(false_fn) File "control_flow_ops.py", line 1895, in BuildCondBranch original_result = fn() File "rnn.py", line 233, in _maybe_copy_some_through new_output, new_state = call_cell() ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2